# How to I write a string before the select statement?

Tags: sql, string, select

What I want to do is write a string so I can format the output of the SQL statement and have it display text before I actually output the rows I have selected.

i.e. The next timesheet ID is [timesheetID]

I'm trying to do it by using;

```
||'The next timesheet ID is'|| select max(timesheet_id) + 1 from funtom_timesheet;
```

Which obviously isn't working, how do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Use something like this

```
Select 'The next timesheet ID is ' || max(timesheet_id) + 1 from funtom_timesheet;
```

or

```
select concat('The next timesheet ID is ',max(timesheet_id)+1) from futom_timesheet;
```

Comment: ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe change the `||` for a `,`?

Comment: That almost works, but it produces "THENEXTTIMESHEETIDIS" as a separate column title, like what "max(timesheet_id)" does

Comment: One other thing, I've added some bits to the code here https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b7bae9f92d6f43dc4f7d4a3e060abd4d

but now it's producing a "not a single-group group function" error, even though i've grouped by the row in question, why is this?